# htaccess redirect ending with number and a letter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Some of my website urls are ending with a 10 digit number and a letter "M" in it. I want to redirect it to my homepage. I am using apache web server.

The url www.example.com/my-page/M1234567890 should redirect to www.example.com

I was trying to achieve this using redirectmatch in .htaccess, but the pattern which i have given in .htaccess is not working. I tried to achieve this in many ways, but not working.

Please see my below code.

```
Redirectmatch 301 ^([C])(d{14})/?$ /
```

Comment: Just `my-page/M1234567890` or `anything-there/M1234567890`?

Comment: Hi @nicael, anything-there/M1234567890.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
Redirectmatch 301 .*/M\d{10} /
```

- `.*/` matches any page and a slash after it (e.g. `qwerty/`)
- `M\d{10}` matches `M` and 10 digits after it

Comment: Thanks @nicael for the quick response. I will try this and will let u know.